# Jasmine Grunt Spec PhantomJS Error on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grunt

I am having problems with **PhantomJS**. When I try to do a **Jasmine Test**. This is my first time running Jasmine.

Things I did prior:

- Installed Grunt
- Executed grunt spec:backend

Do check my terminal logs

```
grunt spec:backend
Running "spec:backend" (spec) task

Running "connect:backend" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:8000

Running "jasmine:backend" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS


PhantomJS threw an error:ERROR
>> 0 [ '' ]
Warning: PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code null. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2017-11-30 06:19:08 UTC+8)
loading tasks                  403ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
spec:backend                   243ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 20%
loading grunt-contrib-connect  136ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
connect:backend                 40ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 3%
loading grunt-contrib-jasmine   72ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 6%
jasmine:backend                339ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 27%
Total 1.2s
```